# invalid type (list) for variable 'train_data'

Tags: r

I am trying to run a linear regression for my loans data frame, however, I keep running into the error below. The data frame has 27393 observations of 30 rows. I believe the glm() function only works with data frames but I tried using as.data.frame() and I still get that same error.

```
library(caTools)

sample <- sample.split(cleaned_loans$new_status, SplitRatio = 0.8)
train_data <- subset(cleaned_loans, sample == TRUE)
test_data <- subset(cleaned_loans, sample == FALSE)

train_data <- train_data[-c(20)] 
train_data <- as.data.frame(train_data)

log.reg <- glm(train_data ~ ., data = train_data, family = "binomial")

Error in model.frame.default(formula = train_data ~ ., data = train_data, : invalid type (list) for variable 'train_data'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be an issue in your formula your line fitting the linear regression. In the first argument, you should have a formula for the response in terms of desired predictors. Instead, it seems you are filling in the data frame. If you replace that first `train_data` with your response name I think you should have more luck. As an example, if I want to fit `mpg` from mtcars on `cyl` and `hp`, disregarding train/test sets for the moment, I would run:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caTools)
log.reg <- glm(mpg ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars)
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: Oh yeah, not sure why i was including the whole data frame instead of the predictor that I wanted. It works now, thank you!